# VB6 Regex Replace

Tags: regex, vb6

```
Dim strPattern As String: strPattern = "[^a-zA-Z0-9]" 
Dim regex As New RegExp
regex.Pattern = strPattern
result = regex.Replace(pFileNameWithoutExtension, "_")
```

It does work but it replace only 1 char. How can I replace more than one char. Example : "ÉPÉ" should be "*P*" but currently the result is : "_PÉ"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just need to enable global pattern matching.

```
Dim strPattern As String: strPattern = "[^a-zA-Z0-9]" 
Dim regex As New RegExp

regex.Global = True

regex.Pattern = strPattern
result = regex.Replace(pFileNameWithoutExtension, "_")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim strPattern As String: strPattern = "[^a-zA-Z0-9]*" 
Dim regex As New RegExp
regex.Pattern = strPattern
result = regex.Replace(pFileNameWithoutExtension, "_")
```

Comment: @Gordon: that just matches a string of 0 or more characters not in the list, it terminates at the first character in the list.